# How to apply transform in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform

Is possible to apply a Transform via script in Unity?

What I mean with "applying" is setting the current position/rotation/scale of an object AS their default ones:
if a game object is rotated by 30° on the x axis, the x rotation value on the Inspector will display 30 of course. By applying the rotation the Inspector will now display 0 and the object will keep its rotation. 30° is now the default rotation of that object.

I know you can do this, for example, in [Blender](https://youtu.be/cZ2zY2ux-pA), but I don't know if it's possible to do it in Unity as well.

Comment: Well in Blender you work on a mesh basis ... in Blender you can also not do this on Object basis. You could ofcourse apply the same transformation also in Unity on a mesh basis but I would not do this ... what is your actual use-case?

Comment: Luckily for you someone already has built this for Unity: https://github.com/mariosubspace/mesh-apply-transform-unity currently this is only for the editor but you can easily extract the required methods for also doing this on runtime if needed

Comment: @derHugo _what is your actual use-case?_ I am still trying to find an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745756/let-the-players-freely-rotate-a-gameobject) question so I was just brainstorming.

Comment: lol, maybe you should rather try ad fix your bug there. It makes this a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since the thing you ask about here is actually way more complex than you think ^^ and actually definitely not what you want to do in order to fix your original issue ...

Comment: uh ok, thanks. I will think of other ways to do it

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "apply" it directly to the object, but you can make a parent object, rotate this object when needed and "apply" the rotation or position to the child object, in this case the model.

**Your hierachy should look something like this**

```
- Parent (this is the object you want to rotate/position/scale)
  - Child (this is the model, you "apply"/set default values to that object)
```